# sda2 contains a file system.with errors , check.forced

Tags: boot, filesystem, bootloader, boot-repair, fsck

Every time i start ubuntu this message will appear and after few seconds another messages appear as shown in picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k0Qe.jpg)

Comment: Do you think you could tell me what it says? My school district will not allow me to view the image (it is blocked within the network!)

Comment: @Jeff The image is pointless. It's just a huge list of "read-only file system" which means that very likely the drive is about to fail.

Comment: A read-only filesystem is bad news; one possibility is HDD failure. Look up how to run a SMART test on your HDD.

Comment: If you can only read your file system, you cannot run your system. Try doing what @user535733 suggested. Or, I would recommend doing a reinstallation of your system, after you back up all important user data to a drive. Here is a few ways you can back up your data: https://www.howtogeek.com/427480/how-to-back-up-your-linux-system/

Comment: Remember to choose files that are not broken when you want to put user data on new installation.